# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint even after deleting the records from the child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I tired to delete the occurrences of the values which the insert stmt was trying to insert 
in the dependent table.

```
delete from BSC_UR_RE_AN 
where AN_ID in (1084,1083,1088,1087,1121,1122,1123,1094,5010,
                1239,1242,70187,7001,7002,1284,1285)
```

But no luck, I got the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "BSC_U_RA_AN_FK".  The conflict occurred in database "DMDB", table
>   "dbo.BSC_AN", column 'AN_ID'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that ANAG_ID value you're trying to insert as FOREIGN KEY doesn't exists on the related table. So, you should not delete it, you should insert it if it's missing.

Edit:
You should have a clear view of your tables design, examining the constraint of the tables you're trying to insert into.

As example, a Foreign Key constraint *usually* refers to a Primary Key of another table.

The error you see is because you're trying to inserd an invalid value (eg. not exists in the master table).

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE MasterTable (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE MasterTableValues (
   IDMasterTable INT REFERENCES MasterTable(ID), --FOREIGN KEY 
   Value varchar(50)
)
```

Let's assume you have this data in MasterTable:

```
1  FirstDate
2  SecondData
3  ThirdData
5  FifthData
```

Now, you can insert these values in MasterTableValues:

```
1  SomeValue
1  SomeOtherValue
3  SomeValue
```

But CANNOT insert this value:

```
4  SomeValue
```

because the key ID = 4 don't exist in MasterTable

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, I think I should try inserting values in the parent table first and then try to insert in the child table.